# Combining Two Arrays & Projecting

Tags: .net, linq

Supposing I have the constructor

```
public SomeObject(string first, string second);
```

and two `string[]` arrays

```
string[] arrayOne = new[] { firstOne, firstTwo };
string[] arrayTwo = new[] { secondOne, secondTwo, secondThree};
```

how can I return an `IEnumerable` or `IList` each element of which is a new `SomeObject` composed of a combination of both array's elements? Currently, I am using

```
IEnumerable<SomeObject> newEnumerable = from stringOne in arrayOne from stringTwo in arrayTwo select new SomeObject(stringOne, stringTwo);
```

but I would prefer something like

```
IEnumerable<SomeObject> newEnumerable = arrayOne.Select(stringOne => arrayTwo.Select(stringTwo => new SomeObject(stringOne, stringTwo));
```

but this last one returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SomeObject>>` which, of course, is not what I want.

Comment: What's wrong with the first query?

Comment: It's not clear how many results you want or what the results should be...

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want - if you're just looking for a version of the first query which doesn't use query expression syntax, you want:

```
var query = arrayOne.SelectMany(x => arrayTwo, (a, b) => new SomeObject(a, b));
```

That's basically what your query expression is being expanded to anyway.

If that's *not* what you want, please make your question clearer. If you want an array at the end, just call ToArray:

```
var array = arrayOne.SelectMany(x => arrayTwo, (a, b) => new SomeObject(a, b))
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I am looking for a way of combining the two arrays, which should result in an array containing 6 `SomeObject` objects.

Comment: @User: This is the first you've mentioned about wanting an *array* as the result. You still haven't said what you don't like about your original query.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the result from the second query using `SelectMany()`:

```
var newEnumerable =
    arrayOne.Select(stringOne => arrayTwo.Select(stringTwo => new SomeObject(stringOne, stringTwo)).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: You can do the whole thing in a SelectMany call with no need for an extra Select call.